# Conda - gather tarballs with dependencies for offline install

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to gather packages for offline install using `Conda`:

```
conda search numpy --info
numpy 1.22.3 py39h7a0a035_0
---------------------------
file name   : numpy-1.22.3-py39h7a0a035_0.conda
name        : numpy
version     : 1.22.3
...
url         : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/numpy-1.22.3-py39h7a0a035_0.conda
```

The `url` is the tarball I am downloading.

The problem I am facing is gathering dependencies:

```
dependencies:
- blas 1.0 mkl
- mkl >=2021.4.0,<2022.0a0
- mkl-service >=2.3.0,<3.0a0
...
```

Is there a way to retrieve the `url` for all dependent packages, to download for offline install?

I thought of re-directing the output to a file, e.g.:

```
conda search numpy --info > C:\Packages\numpy.txt
```

And parsing the file to retrieve dependent packages using Python.

Is there a better way to retrieve all `.tar.gz` files, including dependencies with `Conda`?

Comment: Are source and target machine the same OS? Then you could consider `conda pack`

Comment: @FlyingTeller source and target are same OS, Win 7 64-bit. I will research conda pack. Thanks

Comment: Marking as duplicate - use the `conda-download-all.sh` script.

Comment: @merv Just tested the script it works correctly. One question, does it download all required dependencies, e.g. `-c conda-forge -c pytorch numpy` would download/solve all dependent tarballs for numpy and pytorch?

Comment: Yes, the `conda-download-all.sh` version will do a full solve (all dependencies) and ignores any existing cached packages, such that a fresh copy of everything needed for the environment will be downloaded to the working directory.